# Transpose multiple columns into one columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will transpose phone numbers from n numbers of columns stacked to one column. The scenario is I have a list of clients with multiple phone numbers, and I already have a macro running that will create additional rows per client depending on how many phone numbers a client has. The problems is that the phone numbers are in different columns. Lets say my first client has 3 phone numbers,so on my macro, it will automatically have 3 rows since there are 3 numbers. however, ince those phone numbers are in different columns,i need to get it stacked in one column for those 3 rows.  below is the code I have but it is not working as required.

```vb
    Sub ConvertRangeToColumn()
      'Updateby20131126
    Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim rowIndex As Integer
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    
    Set Range1 = Application.Selection
    Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", xTitleId, Range1.Address, Type:=8)
    Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Convert to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
rowIndex = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each Rng In Range1.Rows
    Rng.Copy
    Range2.Offset(rowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    rowIndex = rowIndex + 
    Rng.Columns.Count

    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: "is not working as required" is not very specific. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73886309/edit) to show us sample data, expected result and explain what exactly the unwanted result is

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your question so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this resource.

https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-transpose-multiple-columns-into-one-column/

Remember, Power Query is very powerful, and Power Pivot is pretty useful too!! Based on my experiences, the former is a bit better than the latter, but it probably depends on your specific use case.

[image]

[image]